# Get attribute value from XML

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have this chunk of XML:

```xml
<show name="Are We There Yet?">
  <sid>24588</sid>
  <network>TBS</network>
  <title>The Kwandanegaba Children's Fund Episode</title>
  <ep>03x31</ep>
  <link>
    http://www.tvrage.com/shows/id-24588/episodes/1065228407
  </link>
</show>
```

I am trying to get "Are we there yet?" via [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org). It is effectively the 'name' attribute of 'show'. I'm struggling to figure out how to parse this.

`xml.at_css('show').value` was my best guess but doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
xml.at('//show/@name').text
```

which is XPath expression that returns the `name` attribute from the `show` element.

Comment: This is close, but it doesn't quite work: `xml.at('//show/@name')` returns a Nokogiri::XML::Attr, not text. `xml.at('//show/@name').value` returns 
`=> "Are We There Yet?"`

Comment: You're right. I tested with `puts`, which does a `to_s` on it. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml =<<EOT
<show name="Are We There Yet?">
  <sid>24588</sid>
  <network>TBS</network>
  <title>The Kwandanegaba Children's Fund Episode</title>
  <ep>03x31</ep>
  <link>
    http://www.tvrage.com/shows/id-24588/episodes/1065228407
  </link>
</show>
EOT

xml = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
puts xml.at('show')['name']
=> Are We There Yet?
```

`at` accepts either CSS or XPath expressions, so feel free to use it for both. Use `at_css` or `at_xpath` if you know you need to declare the expression as CSS or XPath, respectively. `at` returns a Node, so you can simply reference the parameters of the node like you would a hash.

Comment: Super minor aside: I personally prefer and recommend `Nokogiri.XML(…)` over `Nokogiri::XML(…)` as it helps clarify that this is [a method call](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri.html#method-c-XML) and not some weird usage of the [`Nokogiri::XML` module](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML.html). _Plus, it's one fewer character and two fewer key presses (on my keyboard)._

Comment: I use `Nokogiri::XML` or `Nokogiri::HTML` out of habit. It's how I learned it from their tutorials several years ago. I agree that using the `.` notation is more indicative that it's a method, not a constant.

Comment: @Phrogz I'm in the same boat as the Tin Man, but since your comment above (which I also agree with), I have switched to that style.